# Can we have a "decline all of user's pending flags" button?

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderator-tools

It comes up rather frequently that a user flags somewhere in the low to high dozens of posts or comments at once. Often they're all based on Data Explorer queries.

Since flagging things en masse like that isn't particularly helpful, frequently mods end up declining each flag individually. This is time-consuming. Not egregiously so, but it does consume time better spent elsewhere.

If a user has, say, more than five flags waiting for review, can we get a button allowing us to decline all of them at once?

Comment: The reason for my DV was that they may have just flagged a lot, all validy. This worries me that people will just batch reject flags.

Comment: @Tim Presumably, if a moderator considers the flags valid, they would not click that button?

Comment: @Tim This would be used only where a moderator would decline each flag individually anyway; this just saves time on a process people already sometimes do.

Comment: We don't get many flags on either of the sites I mod for so I don't know whether this makes any sense, but I wonder whether a similar result could be accomplished by just having a "bulk decline" option, where you check off several flags individually then decline them all. I think that would resolve Tim's concern, since there would be per-flag action, but it would also be a lot less tiring than having the page flash as you individually decline and give a reason for each. That said, I do support this as-is. It's important on bigger sites to have flag processing be as easy as possible for mods.

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat I think that Tim's concern is that the flags would be declined *without being viewed*.

Comment: Right, the concerning scenario would be a user flagging a bunch of stuff, and the latter half of it is legit, and maybe there's a spam or offensive flag in there, but the moderator sees the first three or four, thinks it's wasting their time and declines the lot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As a moderator on Stack Overflow who's seen a *lot* of terrible flaggers, I'm unfortunately going to have to disagree with this request.

Even on SO, where we do have a lot of flaggers who really waste our time, the cases where we'd want to use this would be rare. The really poor flaggers (the "plz answer my question urgent", the ones who flag viable answers that compete against theirs for deletion, and even the ones who run blind SEDE queries) tend not to cast all of their terrible flags at once. They tend to flag a few things at a time, wasting our time over a longer span with individual flags.

To have a button like this, we'd still need to take the time to review all of someone's flags first before declining. Even the worst flaggers from data queries, etc., will usually have some good flags in there. We won't want to blindly decline those with the rest. This won't save us much time in the end.

Also, from the standpoint of a moderator, all it would take is one or two good flags getting declined out of a pile of bad ones to make a spectacle on Meta. People love a good piling-on when it comes to a moderator's mistaken handling of a flag. A moderator can't show the dozens of bad flags someone has cast as a counterpoint to them accidentally declining a good flag.